Opensea not showing contract metadata
I have deployed my solidity contract to Arbitrum Sepolia network. The contract should manage ERC721 NFTs. Now I have trouble with opensea.testnets showing the metadata for Contract itself(bunner, item image, description are not shown - no matter how long I wait).
Opensea testnets: https://testnets.opensea.io/collection/rrr-winery-emission-september-2024 .
Here is my validated contract:
https://sepolia.arbiscan.io/address/0xf9eee1577ff8a4649068cce00f258665f50aaa7f#readContract
ContractURI: ipfs://bafkreigchi2m364gv7ho7pzkpn56pf3shdyn22qvf56mbjpfctpr4h723q
The content looks fine to me:
curl https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafkreigchi2m364gv7ho7pzkpn56pf3shdyn22qvf56mbjpfctpr4h723q                                                                            
{
  "name": "FGH Winery Emission September 2024",
  "description": "FGH Winery Emission September 2024. Total number of bottles 2",
  "image": "https://previews.123rf.com/images/sayu/sayu1807/sayu180700079/114882995-wine-bottle-clip-art.jpg",
  "banner_image": "https://c7.alamy.com/comp/2PRR8MB/set-with-bottles-of-different-alcohol-drinks-on-white-background-banner-design-2PRR8MB.jpg",
  "external_link": "https://external-link-url.com"
}

Actually I deployed the contract already many times, and sometimes the very same contractURI was working. Lately not. Cannot find the pattern what is wrong.

I can see the image, traits etc. Can you check again?

@Zartai i think you mean trait and image from token (taken from tokenURI), not from the collection. You can compare with my another contract https://testnets.opensea.io/collection/abcd-winery-emission-september-2024-2 - you can see that bunner, description, external_url are rendered. The funny part that the contractURI json contents are identical.

Got help from Opensea support. They told me that my tokenURI was from time to time not available and suggested to change IPFS provider. And indeed, as soon as I started to use Pinata instead of web3storage the issue has gone.
